# reactive forms setValidator and updateOn

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to set a validator on a formControl dynamically and can't seem to get the updateOn: "blur" to work properly.  Instead of on blur it seems to be checking on change.  Is there something special I need to do to get this to work on blur instead of on change.

```
this.form.get("deviceInfo").controls.deviceNumber.setValidators({validators: [Validators.required, this.checkDeviceExists()], updateOn: 'blur'});
```

added the updateValueAndValidity() but still fires on change instead of blur

```
var deviceInfo = this.form.get("deviceInfo");

deviceInfo.controls.deviceNumber.setValidators({validators: [Validators.required, this.checkDeviceExists()], updateOn: 'blur'});
deviceInfo.controls.deviceNumber.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: The updateValueAndValidatity need to be called to trigger the validator functions

Comment: So I added that right after the setValidators and it still fires the async validator on change instead of blur

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example showing dynamic  validation

```
this.form.get('company_name').setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(45)]));      


this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: How do you set the updateOn: 'blur' using validators.compose.  It doesn't like me adding it in there.

Comment: why dont you set the onBlur property at the time of form initiliasing and just apply validations dynamically .? @CoreyWitherow

Comment: Is it possible to set updateOn: 'blur' after the form control is initialised? There is a specific scenario, where we have access to the form that is created by some other service, and we need to update some field with this.

Comment: @Sriram see [this article](https://medium.com/@theykillimmortal/dynamically-changing-of-angular-updateon-option-and-validation-behavior-7acc7f93f357)

Comment: Thanks @ChristianJensen, though it works, it involves copying the value and state of the previous form control. But this is the only possible way with which it can be updated now.

Answer (score 2):

I have the solotion this below :

Please add null validators when create FormControl for FormBulder :

```
taxCode: [null, { validators: null, updateOn: 'blur' }]
```

Then add new Validators with the condition :

```
this.editForm.get('taxCode').setValidators(Validators.compose([isTaxcode]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is described in https://medium.com/@theykillimmortal/dynamically-changing-of-angular-updateon-option-and-validation-behavior-7acc7f93f357

The approach is to use `setControl()` instead of `setValidators()`, which allows construction of an entire control (including the all-important `AbstractControlOptions` and `updateOn` property).

e.g.

```
const oldControl = this.form.get('deviceInfo.deviceNumber');

const newControl = this.formBuilder.control(oldControl.value, { 
    validators: [Validators.required, this.checkDeviceExists()], 
    updateOn: 'blur' 
});

this.form.setControl('deviceInfo.deviceNumber', newControl);
```

This seems overkill to me, in my opinion `setValidators()` should allow passing an `AbstractControlOptions` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.form.setControl('deviceInfo', 
   new FormControl(this.form.controls['deviceInfo'].value,
     {
      validators:[Validators.required,],
      updateOn: 'blur'
     })
 );

this.form.get('deviceInfo').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation how your code solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I empathize with OP. I've found the Reactive form controls (v9) never validate the first time they are touched. If I have a required field that currently has a value in it, and the user clicks into the field, erases the value, and then tabs out, the invalid style elements are not applied (red outline, icon, etc.). They only appear at submit or if the user happens to click back into the field and then out again.

Here is my approach to get the validation to trigger immediately upon tabbing out of an invalid field which has never been touched before.

In my controller (note that I have two Reactive forms on the page):

```
blurMe(e){
  let c = this.parentForm.controls[e.target.attributes['formControlName'].value];
  if(!c)
    c = this.childForm.controls[e.target.attributes['formControlName'].value];
  if(c){
    c.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf:true,emitEvent:true});
  }
}
```

On my view, I add a simple (blur) event binding to any control that needs to be immediately validated. (I am using the Clarity framework from vmWare, v3):

```
<input autocomplete="off" clrInput type="text" formControlName="badgeLabel" style="width:36em" (blur)="blurMe($event)" />
```